# Found no suitable importer plugin for QUrl - .dae object in Qt3D

Tags: qt, plugins, qt5, qt3d

I want to learn Qt especially for the 3D functionalities and therefore was following [this tutorial](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/3d-visualisation-using-qt3d-part-1-guido-piasenza).

One part of the tutorial is displaying the mesh from a .dae file called object.dae.
When I tried to run my code for the first time, I got the following error:

```
2:25:52: Starting /home/qt/build-Qt3DTests-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/Qt3DTests ...
Qt3D.Renderer.SceneLoaders: Qt3DCore::QEntity* Qt3DRender::Render::LoadSceneJob::tryLoadScene(Qt3DRender::QSceneLoader::Status&, const QStringList&, const std::function<void(Qt3DRender::QSceneImporter*)>&) Found no suitable importer plugin for QUrl("file:../Qt3DTests/Models/object1.dae")
22:26:00: /home/qt/build-Qt3DTests-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/Qt3DTests exited with code 0
```

I proceeded to clone [the repo (tag: STEP_001)](https://github.com/gpiasenza/Qt3DTests/tree/STEP_001) and try running it but again I receive the same error.

As this was the first Qt tutorial and C++ code I ever did, I am unsure what could be the problem. Does anybody know what is going wrong? Am I missing some module in my installation or something?

Answer (score 1):

The cause might be this (rare) bug in Qt:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-89045

Comment: Did not get to check this yet but thanks for the hint!